# How to use <mat-icon> tag value using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, electron, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation

I newly started writing automation scripts for Electron-based desktop application.
In the application, we have a set of icons with  tags. Below is HTML code from them.

```
<span class="mat-button-wrapper">
<mat-icon _ngcontent-c1="" class="mat-icon material-icons mat-icon-no-color" role="img" aria-hidden="true">more_vert</mat-icon>
</span>
```

Like in other applications, I am not able to use 'more_vert' in findElementBy linkText. 
For Electron based application, how can I use 'more_vert' to find the elements?
Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`By.linkText` works only for `<a>` tags. You can use `xpath` instead

```
 findElement(By.xpath("//mat-icon[.='more_vert']"));
```